# Where can I find the label map file(pbtxt) of ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco when using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I learn object detection on windows 10 with [tensorflow object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

I download ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

After I unzipped the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz` file, I didn't find the pbtxt file.

Where can I find the related pbtxt file of ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco？

I know that there some pbtxt files in `models-master\research\object_detection\data` folder, but which file is related to ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label map is not specific to an architecture, but rather to a dataset (which classes you support, and accordingly you should set the number of channels of the classification layer).
Therefore, you simply need the label map which corresponds to coco, which is `object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

Dataset is implemented in the model. Model is delivered by tar.gz or .zip. If you use pretrained basic model, then label map can be found code tree githup object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt as netanel-sam explains.

But if you start to train your pretrained model and add items to be detected to your dataset and start to deliver  your modified model, then your must offer your label map also and there is no better way than include it to the .tar.gz or .zip. Same situation is with lite-model, because conversion from trainable model to lite often loses items from dataset. Lite-model uses also other format to labelmap than basic model. Confusing?